# Why does a Hidden Window appear when taking a screenshot in WPF using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, window

I have a `WPF` application that helps me take Screenshots of the entire screen.

The application contains a small Window with a button inside, which if I click on, a capture of the screen is taken, and saved on my drive.

I wanted to hide this little Window just before the capture is taken, so it won't be included in the capture, here's what I tried :

```
StartSnipping = new RelayCommand(() =>
                 {
                   // I hide it here !!
                   WindowVisibility = Visibility.Hidden;                              

                   //Than I take the screen shot
                   var screen = Screen.PrimaryScreen;
                   var bitmap = new Bitmap(screen.Bounds.Width, screen.Bounds.Height);
                   using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                   {
                     graphics.CopyFromScreen(new Point(screen.Bounds.Left, 
                                                       screen.Bounds.Top),
                                             new Point(0, 0), 
                                             screen.Bounds.Size);
                   }

                   //I save the screen shot
                   bitmap.Save(@"C:/Users/Aymen/Desktop/test.png", ImageFormat.Png);
                 });
```

Now, assuming that the line :

```
WindowVisibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

really works, well, I'm sure of this because after all that method completes running, the window is indeed hidden.

And assuming that the screenshot is successfully taken and saved and still contains that window, which is supposed to be hidden like 1 second before the screen capture, my question is :

Why this hidden window is still appearing in the screenshot ?? and what should I do to make it not appear in the screenshot ??

Comment: `//give it some time... Thread.Sleep()...` - please learn to do multi threading properly.

Comment: @HighCore thx for the remark, that was a desperate thing I added, deleted now though

Comment: Hard to guess what "WindowVisibility" might mean, there is no property with that name.  The Windows version also matters, Windows 8 treats completely transparent windows differently and you can't capture layered windows with CopyFromScreen() on earlier versions.

Comment: @Hans: Maybe this?  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9ffc1e79-4c16-4fd7-b7fa-268e9d4ee09d/hidereopen-and-close-a-window?forum=wpf

Comment: @HansPassant `WindowVisibility` is a property in the `ViewModel` to which the Visibility property of the Window is bound

Comment: there you go @BenVoigt yes it's just like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure but it seems that using :

```
WindowVisibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

Doesn't help keeping the window from appearing when taking a screenshot, I had to hide the window using the .Hide() method:

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.Hide();
```

That worked just well, bust still doesn't have any explanation why the `Visibility.Hidden` keeps the window appearing in screenshots.